# Processing 3d object programmatically in iOS idk

Tags: ios, 3d, scenekit

I am displaying `3D` object in my Application.

Currently I am doing this using `SceneKit` Framework , and its working as per expectation It support `.obj`, `.stl` and `.dae` format 3D object.

But My actual **requirement** is to processing in  3D object like:
1: Brightness
2: Saturation
3: Warmth (temperature)
4: Vibrance

After spending few hours of searching, I didn’t got any references even any ios App like this.

If any of above is feasible in iOS for 3D object than please let me know.

Do any one have any idea about this.
Any suggestion will be helpful to me.

Comment: This is just too open ended question. What exactly do you want to do? For example; to zoom in/out; you can modify the `pointOfView` property. Being specific will help everyone.

Comment: You can use image processing filters to update your material textures, and/or modify the lighting models and light properties to get the effects you intend to.  Again, as for lighting, you have support for both classical rendering (blinn etc) and phyiscall based shading (PBR). This is all I can say to your generic question.

Comment: ActualIy i am a newbie to scent kit   don't have idea about "update your material textures" how can i update run time.

Comment: If you are a newbie, I would suggest first trying to understand SceneKit with resources (books, tutorials etc) so that you can further understand if it will meet your needs and be able to ask specific questions.

Comment: @dmsurti do you have any idea abut how can i export .obj file after modification

Comment: Assuming you have imported with SceneKit/ModelIO, you have a `SCNScene` instance, which you can export back to `.obj` or `.dae` or `.scn`. See: https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scnscene/1523577-write https://developer.apple.com/reference/modelio/mdlasset/1391036-export. But please don't add further questions to comments, let the thread be for one thing.

Comment: @dmsurti i have ask another question for that : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41373803/scenekit-modification-in-3d-object-and-exporting-file .