# SceneKit modification in 3D object and exporting file

Tags: ios, 3d, scenekit

In my Application, I am displaying 3D object in SCNView using SceneKit Framework and export the modified file with some small changes like color, Temperature etc. But I am getting the original file after exporting it to the document folder.

Here I can display and do some modification in 3D objects, That looks good and I can see the changes in SCNView in Simulator.

```
    sceneView = [[SCNView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,  self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 100)];
    [sceneView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:sceneView];
    sceneView.allowsCameraControl = true ;
// Load 3D object
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@“test”   ofType:@"obj"];
    NSURL * url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    scene = [SCNScene sceneWithURL:url options:nil error:nil];
    sceneView.scene = scene ;

    // Processing---
    SCNLight *light =[[SCNLight alloc] init];
    light.type = SCNLightTypeAmbient;


    SCNNode *lightNode = [[SCNNode alloc] init];
    lightNode.light = light ;

    // Camera node
    SCNCamera *camera = [[SCNCamera alloc] init];
    SCNNode * Cameranode = [[SCNNode alloc]init];
    camera.saturation = 0.5 ;

    [scene.rootNode addChildNode:Cameranode];


    Cameranode.position =  SCNVector3Make(0.0, 0.0, 30.0);

    sceneToExport = sceneView.scene ;
    // Rotation -
    SCNNode *cubeNode = [[SCNNode alloc] init];
    cubeNode.rotation = SCNVector4Make(1000.0, 0.0, 30.0 , 40.0);
    [scene.rootNode addChildNode:cubeNode];
```

Now I am Trying to export the 3D(.obj) file that I have modified.

```
- (IBAction)saveAction:(id)sender {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //Get the docs directory
    NSString *exportPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sceneAssets.obj"];

    //NSLog(@"Saved %d",[sceneView.scene writeToURL:[NSURL URLWithString:exportPath] options:nil delegate:nil progressHandler:nil]);
   NSLog(@"%d",[assetsToExport exportAssetToURL:[NSURL URLWithString:exportPath]]);


}
```

Here I have tried both ways (MDLAssets and SCNKit) by using this .obj file is saving in Document directory by both methods but I am getting original file instead of the modified object.

I have also tried with creating `MDLAsset` object using SCNScene but get the same result.

Comment: Did you figure out how to save out the modified 3D and export it out?